# Python - Parse file into outputs based on magic number/length

Tags: python, string

I'm a complete beginner to coding - only started 3 weeks ago, and really only have codecademy's Python course under my belt - so simple explanations would be really appreciated!

I'm trying to write a python script that reads a file as a HEX string, and then parses the file into individual output files based on finding a "magic number" within the HEX string.

EG: if my HEX string were "0011AABB00BBAACC00223344", I might want to parse this string into new output files based on the magic number "00", and telling python that each output should be 8 characters long.  The output for the example string above should be 3 files that contain the HEX values:

"0011AABB"
"00BBAACC"
"00223344"

Here's what I have so far (assuming in this case that the string above is contained within the "hextests" file

```
import os
import binascii

filename = "hextests"

# read file as a binary string
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()

# convert binary string to hex string
hexString = binascii.hexlify(content)

# define magic number as "00"
magic_N = "00"

# attempting to create a new substring called newFile that is equal to each instance magic_N repeats throughout the file for a length of 8 characters
for chars in hexString:
    newFile = ""
    if chars == magic_N:
        newFile += chars.len(9)

# attempting to create a series of new output files for each instance of newFile - while incrementing the output file name
    if newFile != "":
        i = 0
        while os.path.exists("output_file%s.xyz" % i):
          i += 1
        fh = with open("output_file%s.xyz" % i, "wb"):
            newFile
```

I'm sure I have a lot of errors to work through on this - and it's likely more complicated than I think .... but my main question has to do with the proper way to define the `chars` and `newFile` variables.  I'm pretty sure python sees `chars` as only single characters in the string, so it's failing because I'm attempting to search for a `magic_N` that is longer than 1 character.  Am I correct that that is part of the issue?

Also, if you understand the main goal of this script, any other thoughts about things I should be doing differently?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: for character match try find() and slicing method and iterate it over your string and append result to a list or dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
filename = "hextests"

# read file as a binary string
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    content = f.read()

# You don't need this part if you want
# to parse the hex string as it is given in the file   
# convert binary string to hex string
# hexString = binascii.hexlify(content)

# Remove the newline at the end of the string
hexString = content.strip()


# define magic number as "00"
magic_N = "00"

i = 0
j = 0
while i < len(hexString) - 1:
    index = hexString.find(magic_N, i)

    # This is the part which was incorrect in your code.
    with open("output_file_%s.xyz" % j, "wb") as output:
        output.write(hexString[i:i+8])

    i += 8
    j += 1
```

Note that you need to explicitly call `write` method to write the data to the output file.

Here it is assumed that the chunks of data are exactly 8 hex symbols long and they always start with `00`. So it's not a flexible solution but it gives you an idea on how to tackle the problem.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much.  I was doing some reading based on another comment on the .find method.  Exactly what I needed...... after realizing that my HEX search was failing due to stupid capitalization... geesh

Comment: @occvtech, Good. If you're happy with the answer you can accept it to show that the problem was solved.

Comment: Woops - thought I did that.  Thanks for the reminder.  Also - just because I know this will come up for future projects -- instead of parsing outputs based on a length of `hexString` - how would I define a footer such that the `hexString` started at the `i` index and ended at the index some other magic number (i.e. a footer)?

Comment: @occvtech, Well I suppose you can use the find method twice. The first time is to find the index of the first occurrence of the `00` magic number and then use the method `find` excluding the returned index. For example, the returned index is 5: `first_index = 5`. Then you use `find` again like this: `second_index = hexString[first_index + 1:].find(magic_N, i)`. And the knowing the first and second indices you can find the length of the output.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense.  I'll have to play with it.  You've been a huge help - seriously thank you.  This is my first coding project outside of codecademy - feels awesome :)